# "edit, build, refresh browser" approach in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

New_bie_developer_from_php_background.

I am developing an asp.net MVC web app using vs2017 community edition.

I want to make my development environment in such a way that I can edit code, build and refresh the browser to see the changes and again you can edit without stopping the server.

But in VS the approach is different. You have to stop the server, edit code, start server again (which makes the server code uneditable).

Does the vs can be modified to match my requirements? ie to edit, build and refresh the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution can be to start your app in a Launch without Debug mode (Ctrl+F5).

That way, ASP.NET will be automatically picking up changes you are making in your code. However, in this mode you will lose debug features (hitting breakpoints, getting debug-related messages etc.).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. First is to click on pause [image: pause]

or use keyboard shortcut keys (Ctrl+Alt+Break). Edit your code and click continue.

Second is by go to Properties of your project (by right clicking project in visual studio's solution explorer) => select Web from left nav and check the Enable Edit and Continue checkbox. Now you can add break point and when it get hit you can edit your code. Now Refresh your browser.